# Installed MAMP on windows & loaded wordpress but have get HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: wordpress, mamp

What I have done: 
Apache Port set to 9000 
Location of wordpress folder is C:\MAMP\htdocs. 
Folder is called wordpress 
Went to phpMyAdmin and created DB 
Went to wp-config-sample.php and updated DB = wpTest, username & password = 'root' 
changed wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php 
Servers are started.

What displays in chrome browser OK:

```
http://localhost:9000/MAMP/
http://localhost:9000/wordpress/readme.html
```

http://localhost:9000/wordpress/ gives the error in browser:

```
This page isn’t working 
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I am therefore unable to set up wordpress.

One thing I have noticed is that MAMP and htdocs folder properties when read only is unchecked and applied and I open it again then read only is checked again.
I have given all users full control in security settings.

Thanks

Comment: Tough to say exactly what's up, but my guess would be something wrong with the .htaccess file -- What you should do is track down the location of the php_error.log file (probably in the /logs directory of MAMP) and see what the most recent output is when you get this error.

Comment: This was found in the phperror.log file                                                   
[02-Jul-2017 05:29:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  
    require_once(C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
    C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php on line 49
[02-Jul-2017 05:29:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed 
    opening required 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php on line 49

Comment: sorry about the messy formatting as I ran out of time.  On line 49 this is what it says:  require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php' );    What do I need to do now?

Comment: There is no wp-includes folder in the wordpress folder (called wordpress) C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress/wp-includes/load.php.                                            What could be the reason for that as I went to wordpress site and downloaded wordpress and that was what I put in the htdocs folder.

Comment: Ouch, yeah, that'd be you problem :)  Not sure why that folder wouldn't be there, but I'd redownload (maybe save your wp-config.php file just to save having to reenter that info) and then try again. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the unzipping program I used to extract the wordpress files did not unzip correctly and the files within the folders wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes were displayed but not the folders themselves. Several times I downloaded & unzipped the wordpress files and all with the same results.
**I changed the unzipping programming and the folders were correctly unzipped.
In the past I have had an unzipping program fail to extract a file but never extract the files incorrectly like this before.**
Initially without the folders the path to load certain files was incorrect and they couldn't be found and hence the error:

```
This page isn’t working 
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```